# Terraform Bigquery Table Schema in a separate JSON file

Tags: google-bigquery, terraform

I know we can define table schemas in Terraform files. My question is, Is there a way to define schemas in separate files and Terraform import it at run time. That way it will be offer better management and readability

```
 resource "google_bigquery_table" "default" {
 dataset_id = google_bigquery_dataset.default.dataset_id
 table_id   = "bar"

  time_partitioning {
   type = "DAY"
  }

 labels = {
  env = "default"
  }

 **schema = <<EOF
[
 {
   "name": "permalink",
   "type": "STRING",
   "mode": "NULLABLE",
   "description": "The Permalink"
 }
]** 
EOF

}
```

So basically what I am asking is how can I move the schema portion to separate files and at run time TF imports that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the schema will not be dynamically generated, then you can use the `file` [function](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/file) for this purpose:

```
schema = file("${path.module}/nested_path_to/schema.json")
```

schema.json:

```
[
  {
    "name": "permalink",
    "type": "STRING",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "description": "The Permalink"
  }
]
```

If the schema will be dynamically generated, then you should use the `templatefile` [function](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/templatefile) for this purpose:

```
schema = templatefile("${path.module}/nested_path_to/schema.json.tmpl", { variable_name = variable_value } )
```